# Read a certain line from a text file and only print a part of that line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
test=HelloWorld
test=
test2=blabla
```

How can I only print what comes after `test=`? Thanks!

Comment: `test=` appears twice in your string. Do you want to print what comes after the first occurrence or what comes after the last occurrence?

Comment: Is it possible to print both?

Comment: Iterate over the lines, use a flag when you find whatever string you’re interested which indicates that you should save the next line. Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: Use `line.split('test=', maxsplit=1)[-1]` for each line. But what you want exactly is really unclear.

Comment: Please include the expected output. In particular, do you also want to print "blabla"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
txt = """
test=HelloWorld
test=
test2=blabla"""

for line in txt.split('\n'):
    split = line.split('=')
    if split[0] == 'test':
        print(split[1])
```

String example, you need to load your file correctly, of course.

You can split strings at certain characters with split(), returning you a list.

Comment: If you opened it first with `file = open("filename.txt", "r")` and `contents = file.read()`. When you are done run `file.close()`.

Comment: The 'right' way to open files is to use `with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:`, the file will then get closed by the context manager automatically whatever happens. If you want to read it line by line, just iterate with `for line in file:`.

Comment: @whoknows Note that strings have a `.splitlines()` method to split lines. Also, this wouldn't get the whole line if there is another `=` sign in it. Use `maxsplit=1`  to avoid that. Furthermore, your code would fail with an `IndexError` because of `split[1]` if any line in the file doesn't contain a `=`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that is correct, however he said his textfile looks like this, so nothing to worry here... Also, when I started with python, I was always happy to get the most straightforward solution, without 'try'-blocks or extra parameters. Loading files would also be a problem without pathlib

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use regex to find what comes after text= such as:
     "/.*=(.*)/

Then grab what is in match1.

See here for how to use regex's in Python

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping

Comment: Please add more than just a link to the answer. Linked websites can change later on, so please add the portion of the website that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Run this ([Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820319)):

```
for line in open("filename.txt"):
 if "o" in line:
  print(line)
```

It will show you only lines with the letter "o". If you wanted to remove `test=` ([Source](https://www.journaldev.com/23674/python-remove-character-from-string)):

```
for line in open("palc.log"):
 if "o" in line:
  print(line.replace("test=", ""))
```

I hope this helps.